# How to configure Jersey to access js/css files

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am using Java8 + Maven3.6.3 to create a jersey rest service, which holds a html page and some js/css files.

The html file references the js file, like this:

```xml
<script src="js/jsfile.js">
```

My pom.xml includes:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

and tomcat-information:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>tomcat-run</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/</path>
                            <attachartifactclassifier>server</attachartifactclassifier>                         <attachartifactclassifiertype>jar</attachartifactclassifiertype>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

In my src/main/webapp folder there is a index.html page. I have configured the port to 8080.

If I now call the localhost:8080 via a webbrowser, the index.html could be found, but the referenced js-files were not loaded.

I have tried multiple possibilities to place the js files (in resources, webapp, etc.) and configured the web.xml, but it seems that no combination worked.

So my question is: what is wrong this this?

My web.xml looks at the moment like this:

```xml
    <filter>
        <filter-name>jersey-serlvet</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.packages.to.restResources</param-value>
        </init-param>
            <!-- pass to next filter if Jersey/App returns 404 -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
   
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jersey-serlvet</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

So whats wrong with my configuration? How do I have to configure web.xml to be able to finde static content files (like js/css files in webbapp dir)?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The files go in `src/main/webapp`. This is standard folder structure for a web app with maven. All the static files go in this folder.

Comment: THis was one of my attempts: I created a "js" folder in webapp (as well as css) and put all *.html directly into webapp. I got a 500 in this case.

Comment: Dont run the Jersey app. Comment out the web.xml configuration. See if the static files work.

Comment: ok, the content of web.xml ist right now: <web-app...></web-app>, In src/main/webapp there is an index.html and js/lib.js. The result is, that index.html can be displayed in Webbrowser, but js-files are not loaded. Debug-Tools from Firefox say "loading failed ... ip:port/js/lib.js"

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: Actually its not my project, but as i can see from pom.xml there ist a plugin-section with <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</grouId><artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId><version>2.1></version>

Comment: Is that how you are running the application, wih the Tomcat plugin `mvn tomcat:run`?

Comment: no, i will start it as a java-app: "java -jar name.jar -httpPort=8080"

Comment: So you are running an embedded server. That makes a difference. We would need to know what (embedded) server you are using and see the codethat you are using to configure and run the server. You have a main method that starts the server. We would need to see that.

Comment: i will give my best: i think the main() is encapsulated in any framework: We have a class RestApplication which extends "javax.ws.rs.core.Application" and its empty and a class ApplicationStartBean, which implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener. Hope this information helps